# vba chart X axis

Tags: excel, vba, charts

This is my VBA code.
I am plotting a chart, on which I am displaying a range of values.
I would like to display the year and quarterly on the X axis of my chart.

```
Sub VBAChart2()

    Dim colunmA As Integer
    colunmA = Range("B1").End(xlToRight).Column - 1

    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim xrng As Range

    Set xrng = Range("C2:F2")

back:
Num = InputBox("àéæå ùåøä ìäöéâ áâøó?")
    If colunmA > Num And Num > 0 Then

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlXYScatterLines, Range("L10").Left, Range("L10").Top, 450, 200).Select

        With ActiveChart

        .SetSourceData Source := Range(Range("B2").Offset(0, Num - 1), Range("C3:C6").Offset(0, Num - 1))
        .SetElement(msoElementDataLabelTop)

        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "ùðä åøáòåï"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "îëø SO"

        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrng
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("C1:F2")

        End With

        Else: MsgBox("ðà ìä÷ìéã îñôø ùåøä äîåôéò áèáìä")
        GoTo back

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're suggesting is possible. I'm not aware of there being some convenient way of simply setting some dates/range as `xvalues` and have Excel automatically infer quarters.

However, if you're not restricted to `xlXYScatterLines` chart type and you're free to add another in your source data (on your sheet), you could try the below.

If I create some dummy data like this (yellow cells are `x values`, green cells are `values`):

[image: Source data]

and then use the code below (which refers to the ranges/cells in the image above):

```
Option Explicit

Sub PlotQuarterAndYears()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlLine, ws.Range("L10").Left, ws.Range("L10").Top, 450, 200).Chart

        .ChartTitle.Text = "Some chart"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "ùðä åøáòåï"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "îëø SO"

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = ws.Range("C2:F3")
            .Values = ws.Range("C4:F4")
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I then get this:

[image: Output chart]

Which seems to be what you described. You'd obviously need to adapt for your own source data/ranges/worksheet, but the main takeaway from this is putting your `xvalues` in two rows and plotting a line chart.

Comment: Yep, exactly: _"one axis, one series of axis labels only"_, thanks for the illustration.